# How do I read images that are not saved in the same package as the class in which i need to use them?

Tags: java, image, inputstream, bufferedimage, imageicon

For example, if I'm using this way for getting the images:

```
        InputStream imgpacman2up = Tablero.class.getResourceAsStream("pacmanup1.png");
        BufferedImage pacman2upImg = ImageIO.read(imgpacman2up);
        pacman2arriba = new ImageIcon(pacman2upImg).getImage();
```

How would the route of the image ("In this case "pacmanup1.png") would be modified if the images are saved in a folder from another package of the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting javadoc of [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - **If the `name` begins with a `'/'` (`'\u002f'`), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the `name` following the `'/'`.**
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   ```
>   modified_package_name/name
>   ```
>
>   Where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object with `'/'` substituted for `'.'` (`'\u002e'`).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your image is in the package `aaa.bbb.ccc` use the following `/aaa/bbb/ccc`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is within some folder named "resources" in src, then the below code accesses the image from your java class.

```
InputStream imgpacman2up = SampleTable.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/pacmanup1.png");
        BufferedImage pacman2upImg = ImageIO.read(imgpacman2up);
        pacman2arriba = new ImageIcon(pacman2upImg).getImage();
```

If it is within some other package then the below code accesses the image from your java class.

```
InputStream imgpacman2up1 = SampleTable.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/abc/ab/pacmanup1.png");
    BufferedImage pacman2upImg1 = ImageIO.read(imgpacman2up1);
    pacman2arriba1 = new ImageIcon(pacman2upImg1).getImage();
```